# Qual a diferença entre RestTemplate para o FeingClient do Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Me deparei com uma dúvida:

- Qual a diferença entre o `RestTemplate` (nunca implementei) e o `FeingClient` (já implementei)?

Percebi que os dois possuem a mesma finalidade ou são semelhantes, porém me parece mais simples implementar o `FeingClient`. Tem alguma situação que um é melhor que o outro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom Fernando, como você falou, parece ter a mesma finalidade. 
Já tive a oportunidade de implementar os dois modelos no Spring. O que me serviu como critério de uso de um ou outro foi realmente a finalidade.

Onde usei o `Feign`, e porque usei? 
Como você deve ter notado na sua implementação de Feign, é muito fácil criar interfaces entre sua aplicação e outros serviços, especificando caminhos e métodos de forma muito clara via anotações. Também é facilitado o tratamento de erro e demais retornos através da configuração de *Decoders*. Então em situações que quero fazer uma espécie de "interface" entre a aplicação **A** e a aplicação **B** passando por uma API minha eu uso o Feign.

Já o `RestTemplate`, costumo adotar quando preciso fazer uma chamada pontual a um serviço externo a minha aplicação, tendo em vista que possui uma implementação simples de fazer, sem necessidade de configurações extras como pode ser vista no exemplo abaixo.

```
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String fooResourceUrl
            = "http://localhost:8080/spring-rest/foos";
    ResponseEntity<String> response
            = restTemplate.getForEntity(fooResourceUrl + "/1", String.class);
    assertThat(response.getStatusCode(), equalTo(HttpStatus.OK));
```

Uma boa documentação sobre a implementação de um RestTemplate pode ser vista aqui [The Guide to RestTemplate](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template).

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: obrigado pelo esclarecimento